# websites that only load sections when in view

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, browser

I have noticed a trend where elements of websites do not load until it is in the immediate view.

I would like to do more in depth solo research on this, but I don't know what this convention is called, which proves to be a limitation for modern search engines.

an example would be how disqus comments sections at the bottom of articles will only load after the user scrolls down that far.

Is this part of an html5 technology package? Is it a browser feature? Does it actually remove stress on the server by not loading everything? why wasn't this done years ago?

Thanks for any helpful insight

Comment: Are you talking about elements that load into the page as you scroll down? That's just infinite scroll.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it could be related to the same technology. But I've seen things where entire div holding the article will already be loaded. but a particular element of the page only begins to load once in the view. Not the same experience as the infinite scroll I recognize

Comment: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll. Or there are "Lazy Load" plugins as well. That only load an image when you scroll close.

Comment: Fair enough. The method you're describing makes me think that they're monitoring the x,y of an element, and when it crosses a threshold an ajax call is made. If you have a site that you're looking at, specifically, i would check the network log within the inspector to see if that's the case.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that was helpful, yeah firebug showed that a call didn't begin to be made until I scrolled to the point where it was in view

Comment: @CQM yep yep, looks like that's the technique they're going for. Do you need an example?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes that would be helpful, is this exactly infinite scroll?

Comment: @CQM You should have a look at lazy load, as mentioned above. You can apply `:inViewPort` to selectors to see if it's in the viewport. Then you can run conditional statements and use `ajax` to retrieve the data based on some property of the element you want to match against.

Comment: @Jasper one of these was a perfectly acceptable answer

Comment: @OhGodWhy one of these comments was a perfectly acceptable answer :)